# nginx redirect different roots to different ports

Tags: nginx, redirect, routes, reverse-proxy

After hours of checking documents and stackoverflow, I still cannot figure out how to do this.

this is my nginx.conf:

```
http {
  upstream backend {
      least_conn;
      server 192.168.77.81:8078 weight=4;
      server 192.168.77.231:8078 weight=7 max_fails=1 fail_timeout=1s;
  }

  upstream static_backend {
      server 192.168.77.81:8079;
  }

  server {
      listen       8068;
      access_log off;
      error_log off;
      location / {
          proxy_pass http://backend;
          proxy_set_header   Host    $host;
          proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP   $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      }
      location /static/ {
          proxy_pass http://192.168.77.81:8079;
      }
  }
}

events {}
```

I want to redirect all the http://192.168.77.81:8068/static to http://192.168.77.81:8079/static

but it all results in either 301 Moved Permanently or http://192.168.77.81:8078/static

which drive me crazy

I also have tried alias and root, and they don't work as well

any advice would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

simply just do proxy_pass ~ /static

this "~" took me hours...